# Virgin Router in modem mode, dd-wrt router

Tags: dd-wrt

I have set my Virgin super hub 2 to modem mode. I cannot connect to it via 192.168.100.1 as the virgin media instructions say. I therefore cannot setup my new router with dd-wrt to connect to the internet. I have tried various forums. How do you setup dd-wrt on a router connected to a modem?

Comment: Note for close-voter... it's not broad at all - it has a very specific fix.

Comment: ... or maybe not... :/

Comment: With the new wording, I'm joining the close as 'too broad' fraternity.